# Adding JTable into JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, custom-controls, jcombobox

Is there anyone who know how to put **JTable into JComboBox** ?
(just like date pickers)

I saw many questions of Put JComboBox into JTable. but I want Opposite.

I tried to change code of "put JComboBox into JTable" questions but I have no idea.

Thanks if anyone can help me.

Comment: By adjusting the renderer, you can put any component into a `JComboBox`. See the [combobox tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer). But not really sure that is what you want to achieve

Comment: Your're probably trying to achieve something which shouldn't be done this way. What are you trying to do?

Comment: There is no standard possibility to do what you want. JIDE extension provides [TableComboBox](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/combobox/TableComboBox.html) but it's not a free lib. To do what you want by yourself you have two choices: either you provide a combobox cell renderer which looks like a table row or you simulate combobox using a (non editable) text field, button and popup.

Comment: @user1803551 hi I got a solution and that's what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at one approach here: [DetailedComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14983562/1438660)

A typical use would be to show supporting information of a data class.  For instance, suppose you have a State class, that has:

```
String fullName;
String abbreviation;
String capital;
```

You could use the `DetailedComboBox` to display the 2-digit abbreviation as a combo, but the drop-down would be a table of all of the data.